# PORT setting of docker images in cloudfoundry

Tags: docker, containers, cloud-foundry, gorouter

I tried pushing a docker [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/theiaide/theia) of `Eclipse theia` to cf, however unable to start it (or rather connect to it). The image [exposes](https://github.com/theia-ide/theia-apps/blob/d329db260cc8e96759241198153d9d3fd731f32e/theia-full-docker/Dockerfile#L315) port 3000 with `EXPOSE 3000`. The app works and running it locally opens the default theia home screen

On CF, Sufficient disk and memory are given.
When the default `port` health check is set, cf hangs at starting app.

```
Creating app theia-docker...
Mapping routes...

Staging app and tracing logs...
   Cell 15fcfa4a-a364-4dc2-ab6b-349f5196bd80 creating container for instance bd4b9e65-946f-485a-9de1-5c7fc8d4ad01
   Cell 15fcfa4a-a364-4dc2-ab6b-349f5196bd80 successfully created container for instance bd4b9e65-946f-485a-9de1-5c7fc8d4ad01
   Staging...
   Staging process started ...
   Staging process finished
   Exit status 0
   Staging Complete
   Cell 15fcfa4a-a364-4dc2-ab6b-349f5196bd80 stopping instance bd4b9e65-946f-485a-9de1-5c7fc8d4ad01
   Cell 15fcfa4a-a364-4dc2-ab6b-349f5196bd80 destroying container for instance bd4b9e65-946f-485a-9de1-5c7fc8d4ad01
   Cell 15fcfa4a-a364-4dc2-ab6b-349f5196bd80 successfully destroyed container for instance bd4b9e65-946f-485a-9de1-5c7fc8d4ad01
```

It eventually  comes to `FAILED`

cf logs would show:

```
   2021-06-12T14:37:25.40+0530 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT root INFO Deploy plugins list took: 161.7 ms
   2021-06-12T14:38:24.77+0530 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 2375: connection refused; Failed to make TCP connection to port 2376: connection refused
   2021-06-12T14:38:24.77+0530 [CELL/0] ERR Failed after 1m0.303s: readiness health check never passed.
```

Why is it taking the wrong PORT number?
If I try setting the port in the env variable as `cf set-env PORT 3000`, I would get

```
FAILED
Server error, status code: 400, error code: 100001, message: The app is invalid: environment_variables cannot set PORT
```

I then set the health check is set to `process`. Of course, this would start successfully (failure or not). Checking the logs it can be seen that the app has started successfully.  When I `ssh` into the app (`cf ssh theia-docker`) I am able to curl the application as localhost:3000 and returns the HTML of the homepage.

```
~ % cf ssh theia-docker
bash-5.0$ curl localhost:3000
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="./bundle.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="theia-preload"></div>
</body>

</html>bash-5.0$
```

However, when I try to connect to the app via the application URL I get the error:

```
502 Bad Gateway: Registered endpoint failed to handle the request.
```

The reason I see for this is that the base image I have used for this is based on `docker:dind` and it seems like in the base image ports 2375 and 2376 are exposed.

Why does CF pick the ports exposed in the base image rather than the one exposed in the docker image that is created? Shouldn't the port in the current image take precedence?

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/3465 Seems like a related issue.

Comment: CF will pick the lowest route number exposed by your image by default. In your answer, you listed three ports 2375, 2376, and 3000. By default and this logic, I'd expect it to pick 2375.

Answer (score 3):

Changing the [route mappings](https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/16.13.0/#routes) helped.
The following steps helped:
Get app guid

```
~ % cf app theia-docker  --guid
8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b
```

Add the required port

```
cf curl /v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b -X PUT -d '{"ports": [3000]}'
{
   "metadata": {
      "guid": "8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
      "url": "/v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
      "created_at": "2021-06-12T09:04:51Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-12T17:58:03Z"
   },
   "entity": {
      "name": "theia-docker",
      "production": false,
.
.
.
"ports": [
         3000,
         2375,
         2376
      ],
.
.
.
```

Get the routes attached to the app

```
~ % cf curl /v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b/routes
{
   "total_results": 1,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f",
.
.
.
```

Use the route-guid to find route_mappings:

```
cf curl /v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f/route_mappings
{
   "total_results": 1,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "33bde252-ad3e-49b4-91df-78543ac452b4",
            "url": "/v2/route_mappings/33bde252-ad3e-49b4-91df-78543ac452b4",
            "created_at": "2021-06-12T09:04:51Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-12T09:04:51Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "app_port": null,
            "app_guid": "8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_guid": "21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f",
            "app_url": "/v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_url": "/v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Update the route-mapping using the app_guid, route_guid and app_port:

```
~% cf curl /v2/route_mappings -X POST -d '{"app_guid":"8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b","route_guid":"21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f", "app_port":3000}'
{
   "metadata": {
      "guid": "a62a2ea6-859f-48cc-aa33-a8d6583081da",
      "url": "/v2/route_mappings/a62a2ea6-859f-48cc-aa33-a8d6583081da",
      "created_at": "2021-06-12T18:02:19Z",
      "updated_at": "2021-06-12T18:02:19Z"
   },
   "entity": {
      "app_port": 3000,
      "app_guid": "8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
      "route_guid": "21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f",
      "app_url": "/v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
      "route_url": "/v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f"
   }
}
```

List the route mappings again:

```
~ % cf curl /v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f/route_mappings
{
   "total_results": 2,
   "total_pages": 1,
   "prev_url": null,
   "next_url": null,
   "resources": [
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "33bde252-ad3e-49b4-91df-78543ac452b4",
            "url": "/v2/route_mappings/33bde252-ad3e-49b4-91df-78543ac452b4",
            "created_at": "2021-06-12T09:04:51Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-12T09:04:51Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "app_port": null,
            "app_guid": "8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_guid": "21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f",
            "app_url": "/v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_url": "/v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f"
         }
      },
      {
         "metadata": {
            "guid": "a62a2ea6-859f-48cc-aa33-a8d6583081da",
            "url": "/v2/route_mappings/a62a2ea6-859f-48cc-aa33-a8d6583081da",
            "created_at": "2021-06-12T18:02:19Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-06-12T18:02:19Z"
         },
         "entity": {
            "app_port": 3000,
            "app_guid": "8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_guid": "21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f",
            "app_url": "/v2/apps/8032eea6-d146-4d27-9b17-c7331852b59b",
            "route_url": "/v2/routes/21f89763-baab-456d-8151-aad383a3c28f"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

You will find the new route mapping that was created. Delete the unwanted one.

```
~ % cf curl /v2/route_mappings/33bde252-ad3e-49b4-91df-78543ac452b4 -X DELETE
```

That's about it. Any better solutions are welcome :). (Not involving to maintain the Dockerfile of the base image of course)