# Docker image can bind low port locally, but not in Cloudfoundry

Tags: docker, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to run the [`dpage/pgadmin4` image](https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/) in CloudFoundry.

If I run the image on my machine, the server starts and listens on port 80:

```
$ docker run -t -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=a@b.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=defg" -e "PGADMIN_DISABLE_POSTFIX=true" -p 8080:80 dpage/pgadmin4:6

NOTE: Configuring authentication for SERVER mode.

pgAdmin 4 - Application Initialisation
======================================

[2023-04-03 21:58:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2023-04-03 21:58:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://[::]:80 (1)
[2023-04-03 21:58:18 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: gthread
[2023-04-03 21:58:18 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
::ffff:172.17.0.1 - - [03/Apr/2023:21:58:28 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 217 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

I can push an app to CloudFoundry using the image.  If I don't specify any network parameters, it fails with `[ERROR] Can't connect to ('::', 80)`.  I assumed it was due to a permissions issue, binding a low (restricted) port, and fixed this by setting `PGADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS: 0.0.0.0` and `PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT: 8080`. Now it starts fine, but the web server is listening on port 8080 while the container EXPOSEs ports 80 and 443, and CF apparently uses the exposed ports to determine where to route traffic (so, 80 in this case).

I've seen [this somewhat-related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67951182/port-setting-of-docker-images-in-cloudfoundry) and understand that I could interact with the REST API to change the port routing on the fly, or I suppose I could make a new Dockerfile and build my own image that EXPOSEs 8080 by default, but I'd really like to just get the image running as-is, listening to the default port (80) the way it works on my local machine.

Where I get stuck is: why can `gunicorn` listen on port 80 on my laptop, but not in CloudFoundry?  Is there a setting I can change that would allow it to do so?  Could I be wrong about the cause of the "Can't connect to..." error in the first place?

Comment: FWIW, deriving a new image from that one with `EXPOSE 8080`, the address/port environment variables, and basically nothing else, did solve the problem, but I'd still prefer a solution that doesn't require a custom image.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ports in CF, and I'm not entirely sure which port you're trying to change. It sounds like you have an app packaged in a container image that expects to listen on port 80 inside the container and you want CF to route traffic to port 80, not the default 8080.

This should allow you to change that. From the docs...

> By default, apps only receive requests on port 8080 for both HTTP and TCP routing. Configuring custom app ports allows developers to bring workloads onto Cloud Foundry that receive requests on ports other than 8080.

I would suggest trying the procedure documented here: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/custom-ports.html#overview

> Where I get stuck is: why can gunicorn listen on port 80 on my laptop, but not in CloudFoundry? Is there a setting I can change that would allow it to do so? Could I be wrong about the cause of the "Can't connect to..." error in the first place?

This is a difference between container runtime implementations. [Docker has chosen to allow users to bind to any port (they have set the restricted port range to start a zero instead of 1024)](https://medium.com/@olivier.gaumond/why-am-i-able-to-bind-a-privileged-port-in-my-container-without-the-net-bind-service-capability-60972a4d5496). CloudFoundry has decided to be more strict. It is a shared platform for deploying essentially untrusted applications, so it [needs to be more hardened](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html#security).

Comment: It looks like that's basically the procedure in the issue I linked, where I said I could interact with the REST API to remap ports.  The problem I'm trying to solve is more about Docker than CF, though -- CF is smart enough to automatically remap and route incoming requests to the lowest-numbered EXPOSE port in the docker image, but unfortunately I can't get the subject image to actually listen on the port that's exposed (80).  If I could just figure out why it's unable to listen on port 80, CF would sort itself out, I think.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm following you now. `Where I get stuck is: why can gunicorn listen on port 80 on my laptop, but not in CloudFoundry?` -> I think you answered this. It's a privileged port and that's not allowed on CF. There are some things CF does to harden containers, see https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html#security. It may also be something that docker is going to make life easier, see https://medium.com/@olivier.gaumond/why-am-i-able-to-bind-a-privileged-port-in-my-container-without-the-net-bind-service-capability-60972a4d5496.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, that Medium article you linked is exactly the answer I'm looking for.  To save everyone else a click, the short version is that Docker essentially dropped the definition of a restricted port ("starts at 0 instead of 1024") to encourage people to stop running as root, but not every container runtime has followed suit.  So on my laptop, when the container runs in Docker, port 80 isn't restricted, but in CF, it is.  If you want to add this to your answer, or leave another one, I'd be happy to accept it.